# How to transform XML document with CDATA using JDOM2?

Tags: xslt, cdata, jdom-2

Source document:

```
<content><![CDATA[>&< test]]></content>
```

XSLT document (cdata-transformation.xslt):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="transformed" />

  <xsl:template match="/content">
    <transformed>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </transformed>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Wanted result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transformed><![CDATA[>&< test]]></transformed>
```

Actual result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transformed>&gt;&amp;&lt; test</transformed>
```

Code used to test using JDOM2:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;

import org.jdom2.CDATA;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;
import org.jdom2.transform.JDOMResult;
import org.jdom2.transform.JDOMSource;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CdataTransformationTest {

    @Test
    public void learning_cdataTransformationWithJdom() throws Exception {
        Document xslt = loadResource("xslt/cdata-transformation.xslt");
        Document source = new Document(new Element("content")
                .addContent(new CDATA(">&< test")));

        Document transformed = transform(source, xslt);

        XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
        System.out.println(outputter.outputString(transformed));
    }

    private static Document transform(Document sourceDoc, Document xsltDoc) throws TransformerException {
        JDOMSource source = new JDOMSource(sourceDoc);
        JDOMResult result = new JDOMResult();

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                .newTransformer(new JDOMSource(xsltDoc));

        transformer.transform(source, result);

        return result.getDocument();
    }

    private static Document loadResource(String resource) throws IOException, JDOMException {
        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream inputStream = classloader.getResourceAsStream(resource);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
                return builder.build(inputStream);
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

JDOM version used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

XSLT processor used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have searched around for ways to do this, and the best answers say that what is needed to wrap content in CDATA is to add the tag name in the `cdata-section-elements` attribute. I cannot get this to work with JDOM and not when using the [Free online XSL Transformer](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html) either. I have also tried using saxon instead of xalan, but with the same result.

Why doesn't this work? What am I missing/doing wrong here? Is JDOM ignoring the `cdata-section-elements` attribute?

I have also tried wrapping the content like this:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="." />
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
```

But this produces an unwanted result in JDOM which makes it difficult to work with. Visible when you set the `outputer.getFormat().setIgnoreTrAXEscapingPIs(true);` and it looks really ugly when using pretty format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transformed>
  <?javax.xml.transform.disable-output-escaping?>
  &lt;![CDATA[
  <?javax.xml.transform.enable-output-escaping?>
  &gt;&amp;&lt; test
  <?javax.xml.transform.disable-output-escaping?>
  ]]&gt;
  <?javax.xml.transform.enable-output-escaping?>
</transformed>
```

Comment: FWIW, your method does work with both Xalan and Saxon (see: http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6A) - so the problem is not with the code, but with the processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are transforming to a `JDOMResult`, that is, a tree representation, and not to a stream or file. Output directives like `cdata-section-elements` are only used when the XSLT processor serializes the result to a stream or file, but not when building a result tree in memory. So I think if you want to construct CDATA sections as the result of XSLT with `cdata-section-elements`, you need to make sure you write to a file or stream or at least a StringWriter, then you could load the JDOM result from that file or stream respectively created String.

Rewriting the transform method to:

```
private static Document transform(Document sourceDoc, Document xsltDoc) throws JDOMException, IOException, TransformerException {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    JDOMSource source = new JDOMSource(sourceDoc);
    Result result = new StreamResult(writer);

    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
            .newTransformer(new JDOMSource(xsltDoc));

    transformer.transform(source, result);

    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    return builder.build(new StringReader(writer.toString()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I was not aware of this. Added the modified code needed to make it work in your answer. This produces the desired output.